# How to display SVG content in an <img> tag in Chrome

Tags: jquery, image, jsf, svg

I am using a JSF application and I have designed a internal scheme editor using jQuery. On the load of the page I need to call the XML content from the database and then convert the given XML content to SVG format and display it in the `img` tag. I am able to do the same thing when trying to convert it into JPEG format, but when I convert to svg SVGmat the data is fetched but it's not displayed in the `img` tag. I use Google Chrome for my application. The code snippet is as given below.

```
function initImportImages() {
    createImage("image/svg", applySvg);
} 

//Export the image 
function createImage(imageType, callback) {
    var exporter = createExporter(imageType);
    var value = $("#moleculeTxt").val();
    exporter.render($("#moleculeTxt").val()).then(callback, alert);
}

function applySvg(svg) {
    alert(svg);
    $("#imageContainer").html(svg);
    $("#image").html(svg);
    $("#imageContainer").css("display", "inline-block");
}

//default functions of marvin to render the DB value back to image      
function createExporter(imageType) {
    var inputFormat ="mrv";
    if(inputFormat == "") {
        inputFormat = null;
    }
    var defaultServices = getDefaultServices();
    var services = {};
    services['molconvertws'] = defaultServices['molconvertws'];
    var settings = marvinSketcherInstance.getDisplaySettings();
    settings = {
        'width' : parseInt($("#image").val(), 600),
        'height' : parseInt($("#image").val(), 600) 
        /* 'width' : parseInt($("#image").val(), 600),
        'height' : parseInt($("#image").val(), 600) */
    };
    var params = {
        'imageType': imageType,
        'inputFormat': inputFormat,// type of output image
        'services': services, // to resolve any molecule format and be able to calculate stereo info
        'settings': settings
    }

    try {
        return new marvin.ImageExporter(params);
    } catch(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

XHTML:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <s:div id="imageContainer">
        <img id="image" class="bordered"></img>
    </s:div>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Why a jsf tag and no seam tag? Does it work when you change `s:div` into `div`? Most likely not. So not jsf related. And you are saying it does work in FireFox? If not, remove the chrome tag to

Comment: What does the SVG look like? Are you sure it's valid?

Comment: SVG is a source which is a <cml> data that needs to be converted to string displayed in svg format within the <s:div> tag .